# What is the Ubuntu os loader and where does it reside?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, bios

I am studying for a class on System and Network Engineering and in one material we are told that Ubuntu uses the OS loader to load the bootloader GRUB.

My question is what is the Ubuntu OS loader and where does it reside?

Comment: All your questions should have an answer here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Booting

Comment: @Rinzwind you should turn that into an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume we are talking about a system using a BIOS system. Nowadays we also have UEFI where things are a bit more complicated. The [booting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Booting) (link has more detailed information)  process has 4 stages:

1. BIOS

   - (U)EFI is another form of kind of firmware. BIOS is found mainly on IBM based systems. EFI is from INTEL and UEFI is supported by a wide range of companies (including Redhat, AMD, nVidia, Intel, Microsoft). If you want detailed difference between the two [this website](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) explains it very nicely.

   When a computer is started it starts by executing firmware. In IBM PC compatible systems this is the BIOS and is (mostly) stored on a read only memory module. This will initialise all hardware expect for the CPU and ends with starting the boot loader.
2. Boot loader **Answer to 1st part**

   The boot loader can be activated from several locations.

   1. Master Boot record (The master boot record is the first sector on a disk and contains in general a partition table for the disk and a simple boot loader **Answer to 2nd part**). GRUB (currently default on Ubuntu) and LILO (used to be the Linux default) are examples of this.
   2. A CD, DVD or USB.
   3. A network location.

   At the end of the bootloader section it will start the kernel. The kernel picked for this can be a manual choice or an automated choice (last booted kernel, 1st one on the list etc).
3. Kernel

   - This is the same for all Linux systems though any Linux can use different modules.

   The kernel is the core of all of our Linux systems and provides access to hardware (by loading modules),  load ram disks and several other low level tasks so the system startup can begin.
4. System startup

   - this will be different for Redhat, SUSE, Debian/Ubuntu (etc.) and also different for kde, gnome, unity (etc.)

   First the root partition and filesystem are located, checked and mounted. Next the init process is started, which runs the initialization scripts. These scripts involve different `/etc/rc` scripts and upstart events that eventually gives you a ready-to-use computer with a login screen.

Comment: Now that is an added value!

Comment: I talked to my teacher about this and he said he is referring to the specific Ubuntu OS loader that loads GRUB...and he gave me the clue ¨shim¨. I dont really know what is he talking about.

Comment: That is UEFI he is talking about. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot and control-f for shim. And MOST of us are not using this since it reguraly kills your OS.

Answer (score 2):

The OS loader is Grub. Grub is more than just a bootloader.

**By Default:**

For BIOS computers it's stored in the drive's master boot record on MBR partition tables, and the drive's protected master boot record on GUID partition tables.

For UEFI/EFI computers it's stored on the EFI System Partition.

Sources:

- [Proposal For A New Tag & Synonym Tags To Help Prevent Misuse Of The Bootloader Tag?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9237/proposal-for-a-new-tag-synonym-tags-to-help-prevent-misuse-of-the-bootloader-t)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Booting